# How to fix "Unidentified contract"? OpenSea is unable to “understand” ERC1155

Tags: ethereum, solidity, opensea

I have deployed a **ERC-1155** based contract (based on [OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc1155)) and minted some NFTs on this contract successfully. But when I want to use these NFTs in OpenSea, it always says *"Unidentified contract"*.

Example: https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0xc7d3e4a5A0c3e14ba8C68ea1b8a99a9dBf3ca76F/2

API-Example: https://testnets-api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xc7d3e4a5A0c3e14ba8C68ea1b8a99a9dBf3ca76F/2/?force_update=true

Following their [official Tutorial repository](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-erc1155) (which does not compile any more because of outdated dependencies and other issues) I have added some (maybe) opensea-specific functions and data that might required for OpenSea in order to work properly. However, OpenSea is able to grab all required data to display an NFT, but as long as they say "Unidentified contract", this all makes no sense so far.

My question has:

has someone already managed to deploy a ERC-1155 and used it with OpenSea properly without this issue? Is there anything we have to "register" somehow contracts that are not based on ERC-721?

##### Code to reproduce

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Burnable.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract OwnableDelegateProxy { }

contract ProxyRegistry {
  mapping(address => OwnableDelegateProxy) public proxies;
}


contract MetaCoin is ERC1155, AccessControl, Pausable, ERC1155Burnable {
    bytes32 public constant URI_SETTER_ROLE = keccak256("URI_SETTER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    address proxyRegistryAddress;


    constructor(address _proxyRegistryAddress) ERC1155("https://abcoathup.github.io/SampleERC1155/api/token/{id}.json") {       
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _setupRole(URI_SETTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _setupRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);

        proxyRegistryAddress = _proxyRegistryAddress;
    }

    function setURI(string memory newuri) public onlyRole(URI_SETTER_ROLE) {
        _setURI(newuri);
    }

function pause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _pause();
}

function unpause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _unpause();
}

function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC1155, AccessControl)
    returns (bool)
{
    return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}

    function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE)
    {
        _mint(account, id, amount, data);
    }

    function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE)
    {
        _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address operator, address from, address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
    }

  /**
   * Override isApprovedForAll to whitelist user's OpenSea proxy accounts to enable gas-free listings.
   */
  function isApprovedForAll(
    address _owner,
    address _operator
  ) public override view returns (bool isOperator) {
    // Whitelist OpenSea proxy contract for easy trading.
    ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
    if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(_owner)) == _operator) {
      return true;
    }

    return ERC1155.isApprovedForAll(_owner, _operator);
  }


}
```

##### Environment

node: v16.7.0

deps:

```
"@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.3.0",
"@nomiclabs/buidler": "^1.4.8",
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.2",
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^2.1.1",
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
"@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades": "^1.9.0",
"@typechain/ethers-v5": "^6.0.5",
"@typechain/hardhat": "^1.0.1",
"@types/chai": "^4.2.15",
"@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.3",
"@types/mocha": "^8.2.2",
"@types/node": "^14.14.37",
"chai": "^4.3.3",
"chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
"chai-datetime": "^1.8.0",
"ethereum-waffle": "^3.3.0",
"ethers": "^5.4.5",
"hardhat": "^2.6.1",
"hardhat-typechain": "^0.3.5",
"ts-generator": "^0.1.1",
"ts-node": "^9.1.1",
"typechain": "^4.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.2.4"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the root cause! OpenSea expects a public property called `name` in order to display the proper Name of the Collection instead of a static label *Unidentified contract*.

I came across this while looking at their [reference code](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-erc1155/blob/master/contracts/ERC1155Tradable.sol#L28) (which depends on a now 3-year-old [MultiToken-Contract implementation](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/multi-token-standard) and needs all in all some downgrades of Node and other tools in order to get it build [a downgrade to Node 10 worked best for me today] ).

Comment: I've followed this tutorial for the bulk upload: youtu.be/VglTdr0n5ZQ?t=1496. The images are there on the testnet and as I've defined the variable `name` in my contract, the Unidentified contract - DmXmQaXXXX issue has been solved but, how we could upload a folder to an existing collection we own on the OpenSea? Cause right now, when I use the existing collection name, it creates a new collection V2!

Answer (score 10):

This is taken from `name` in your contract.

For ERC-1155 tokens, add a public variable `name`

`string public name = "My Collection Name";`